# How to validate multiple forms in a single component ?(Reactive Forms Validation)

Tags: angular

```
<div class="modal-body">
<ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="pill" href="#EmployerLogin">Employer</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#seekerLogin">Candidate</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="EmployerLogin" class="tab-pane  active">
        <form class="form-horizontal" [formGroup]="registerForm" (ngSubmit)="employerLogin()">
            <input type="email" [(ngModel)]="emplogin.employer_email" formControlName="elogin" name="empname" class="form-control"
                [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.elogin.errors }" placeholder="Email">
            <div *ngIf="submitted && f.elogin.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                <div *ngIf="f.elogin.errors.required"> Email is required</div>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-default">Login</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="seekerLogin" class="tab-pane fade">
        <form class="form-horizontal" [formGroup]="registerForm" (ngSubmit)="seekerLogin()">
            <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="seekerlogin.seeker_email" formControlName="empEmail" name="empname"
                class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.empEmail.errors }" placeholder="Email">
            <div *ngIf="submitted && f.empEmail.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                <div *ngIf="f.empEmail.errors.required"> Email is required</div>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-default">Login</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

### login.ts

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
    @Component({
        selector: 'my-Header',
        templateUrl: './header.component.html',
    })
    export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
        constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }
        registerForm: FormGroup;
        ngOnInit() {
            this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
                elogin: ['', Validators.required]
            });
        }
        submitted: Boolean = false;
        // Employer  Login Method
       get f() { return this.registerForm.controls; }

        employerLogin() {
            this.submitted = true;
            if (this.registerForm.invalid) {
                return;
            }
        }
        // Seeker  Login Method
        seekerLogin() {
            this.submitted = true;
            if (this.registerForm.invalid) {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

How to validate both forms ,when i am trying to validate one of them its showing error for both side.is there any other way to validate multiple forms in a single component using  Angular 6.Please note I am very new to Angular 6 and typescript, so I might be missing something obvious. :)

Comment: What is `f` in this `f.errors` in your Template?

Comment: I have edited my code .now you can check

Comment: What exactly is your use case? Why are you using the same form? Any specific reason for that? You could have created two different `formGroup`s to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're using the `submitted` boolean property to check for both the forms and each has a field that has a `Validators.required` applied to them, it won't be possible with just one `FormGroup`.

You will have to either create two different `FormGroup`s altogether or you'll have to create two different `FormGroup`s in the same `registerForm` `FormGroup`.

I'm going to show the latter approach in this answer:

Here's your Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }
  registerForm: FormGroup;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      employerGroup: this.formBuilder.group({
        elogin: ['', Validators.required]
      }),
      candidateGroup: this.formBuilder.group({
        empEmail: ['', Validators.required]
      })
    });
  }
  employerSubmitted: boolean = false;
  candidateSubmitted: boolean = false;
  // Employer  Login Method
  get fe() { return (<FormGroup>this.registerForm.get('employerGroup')).controls; }

  get fc() { return (<FormGroup>this.registerForm.get('candidateGroup')).controls; }

  get employerGroup() {
    return this.registerForm.get('employerGroup');
  }

  get candidateGroup() {
    return this.registerForm.get('candidateGroup');
  }

  employerLogin() {
    this.employerSubmitted = true;
    if (this.registerForm.invalid) {
      return;
    }
  }
  // Seeker  Login Method
  seekerLogin() {
    this.candidateSubmitted = true;
    if (this.registerForm.invalid) {
      return;
    }
  }

}
```

And then in your Component Template, bind to these FormGroups:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="pill" href="#EmployerLogin">Employer</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#seekerLogin">Candidate</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="EmployerLogin" class="tab-pane  active">
            <form class="form-horizontal" [formGroup]="employerGroup" (ngSubmit)="employerLogin()">
                <input type="email" formControlName="elogin" name="empname" class="form-control"
                [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': employerSubmitted && fe.elogin.errors }" placeholder="Email">
            <div *ngIf="employerSubmitted && fe.elogin.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                <div *ngIf="fe.elogin.errors.required"> Email is required</div>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-default">Login</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <br>

    <div id="seekerLogin" class="tab-pane fade">
        <form class="form-horizontal" [formGroup]="candidateGroup" (ngSubmit)="seekerLogin()">
            <input type="text" formControlName="empEmail" name="empname"
                class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': candidateSubmitted && fc.empEmail.errors }" placeholder="Email">
            <div *ngIf="candidateSubmitted && fc.empEmail.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                <div *ngIf="fc.empEmail.errors.required"> Email is required</div>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-default">Login</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-2ewwrf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for your ref.

Comment: Thank you for explaining very briefly.For validation purpose both forms are working fine but when trying to submit one of them its not working.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a form structure like this:

```
MasterForm = this.formbuilder.group({
grp1 = new FormGroup({
   formControl1,
   formControl2
}),
grp2 = new FormGroup({
   formControl3,
   formControl2
})
}, { validator: matchEmailsDomain(formControl1,formControl3)});
```

Create this form in some service. And now in your component get form object using some method of service like this:

```
getFormObject(){
   return this.MasterForm;
}
```

In your component then you can do something like this:

```
ngOnInit(){
   this.myUserForm = this.myFormService.getFormObject();
}
```

and in html use this myUserForm as [formGroup]="myUserForm ";

In your validator

```
export function matchEmailsDomain(fc1, fc2): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: FormGroup): ValidationErrors | null => {

       // your validator logic here

    };
}
```